# How to Explain Coding is not just Copy and Paste to non Software Developers?

Tags: project-management, project

We have 6 people in my group.  My boss and the others are all SQL developers with little understanding of programming, design patterns, good object oriented design, etc.  But, they have all taken a Java course in college.

When new projects come up, I am usually asked to give a time estimate for how long my part will take.  If this project is needed with quick turn around and they don't like the estimate I have given them, they will look at previous modules/portlets I have built and say things like, "It basically looks the same as Project X, so you should be able to just copy/paste that code and modify the SQL a little.  You should be able to do this in 1/2 the time you gave us".

Recently, it got so bad, my boss called me into a daily status update meeting with the group there, and each of the SQL developers asked me why I couldn't just copy/paste the existing code.  They even `took the wiki documentation I created` from the previous projects and **began explaining my documentation to me**.

Has anyone else ran into this?  How do you handle this?

Comment: invite them to do it themselves and then crack down on the result

Comment: Leave. The odds are stacked against you.

Comment: Sometimes coding IS a matter of copy/paste/modify/tune (e.g. SQL that supports basic CRUD without business logic).  Sometimes though it is a terrible idea.  Can you provide more details about your requirements?

Comment: I've come REALLY close to both your suggestions before.  But, I'm wondering if there is a better way to explain this more diplomatically.  thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I effectively explain technical concepts to a non technical boss when I'm not a good talker?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/136846/how-can-i-effectively-explain-technical-concepts-to-a-non-technical-boss-when-i)

Comment: Please consider searching "how to explain" and a few more of your keywords here on the site.  You'll find a wealth of questions to consider and help guide you.

Comment: @GlenH7 The problem here seems to be that the boss IS technical. At least he belies he is. There is huge difference in that.

Comment: @Euphoric - then have a look at: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/167744/53019  :-)  Like I said, there's a wealth of already answered Q&A on the site covering this problem.

Comment: If your previous code was made with understanding of programming, design patterns, good object oriented design, etc. shouldn't it be fit for copying? ;-)

Comment: One thing to consider: if the modules _are_ that similar, why have you not abstracted the common bits out so it's less clearly a copy/paste issue?

Comment: "How to explain" questions always seem to be really "How to force them to agree" questions.  You're in a place where slapping something together and getting it out the door is the priority.  They arent going to change their minds until that attitude comes back to haunt them in a very bad way, and they have to deal with the consequences.

Comment: I would put this as an answer but oh look, this has been put on hold. You're dealing with the classic case of "a little bit of knowledge is a dangerous thing". Given that they are at least semi-technical you could try to persuade them with an example of something they can understand. Since they know SQL, find a complex SQL statement (preferably one actually used at your work) and demonstrate how copy/pasting and adapting it to a different situation can go horribly wrong. Note that this may not work if that's how they actually use SQL already...

Comment: @GrandmasterB maybe you're right but at the same time this is an issue with people who think they understand some professional field.  Slapping it together isn't really the answer since it will only come back to bite the OP, not the SQL guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you are too conservative or they are too aggressive in thier estimates.  If times are different, then you will need to validate your estimates and assumptions in detail for others to view and come to consensus on.  One can't just say, "it should take 3 weeks because it looks like project X".  You will need to go deeper.

Estimates usually come in 2 forms:

- High Level
- Detailed

Usually esimates start in high level form.  A high level estimate is maybe T-Shirt size like XS, S, M, L, XL, and XXL.  There are usually used to define how big the project will be.  If everyone agress on the same size, then no need to go any further.

However, if you are saying medium and they are saying extra small, then you need to go into a more detailed estimate that lists out all the assumptions, desired functionality, and corresponding effort (tasks) to justify the medium effort.  This should flush out any differences so that all parties agree on the estimated effort of the project.  How deep should you go?  For estimation purpose, maybe a high level view of the proposed system that will be built, components, and broad tasks needed to build those components.

If you are doing the same things over and over again, then I would have to agree that things should take less time the second, third, fourth time around.  Certainly accessing a database should be a common component that can be re-used.  You could develop starting templates for CRUD type operations so you are not starting from scratch every time.

Also, if you justify your estimate and everyone else still says something different, then they are not being logical or reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

Problem with copying is that you copy the bugs also and you add new features only to the last 'current' copy.

When copying bugs over you may end up with a maintenance culture where you have to fix bugs many many times for each separate copy. As time passes and the code loses simularity bug fixing isn't 'copying' anymore. One fix won't quite fit on the other project etc.

When you add new features that you want to retrofit to a project that was source of a copy in the past the business may expect it would be easy, in practice not so much, the code bases will stray away from each other with time.

Refactoring is a big no-no, knowing that if you improve code on project A you'd still be stuck with the painful experience on all the other projects. Doing a complex refactoring 10 times? I don't think so.

If project A is only a few line changes from project B maybe you can just use project A's code as is and share between A and B. Add configuration options to differentiate between A and B. Create a framework, configurable application or service. Etc.

Having said that. I do copy code a lot, but only for scaffolding purposes. I aggressively remove any code not needed and I look for parts that could potentially be moved to a library and shared that way. This is a valid way of working if project A and project B are expected to have different axis of change (they are similar now but won't be further into the future).

Constantly looking for commonality and coming up with increasingly abstract and therefor vague components has it's limits also. Draw a line somewhere and just fork for dissimilar domains.